# TabBarController in NavigationController does not show TabBar in viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UITabBarController to whose controllers I would like to attach navigation. So I inserted the NavigationController as the entry controller, and the tabBarController as its root. All seems working fine, but for the tabBar. Basically it does not show, albeit the StoryBoard I attach seems to say differently. I also attach the Account Screen not showing any navigation bar nor, of course, any back button.

Thanks,
Fabrizio

[image: StoryBoard]
[image: Example screen]

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick answer. I think you should put `UINavigationController` inside the `TabBarController` instead of the other way round. It will solve most of your problems.

Steps: **Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller**

See the below screen shot on how to add a Navigation Controller to a View Controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are following wrong approach, IOS does not allow you to use tabbarview controller as root of navigation controller, it always display black screen. I have faced same problem and as a solution i have added navigation bar after tabbar controller. Yes it becomes difficult to manage, but you can use that way and it will work.
If you use programmatic approach instead of storyboard then it is possible, see [this link](http://www.wiredbob.com/2009/04/iphone-tweetie-style-navigation.html)
Even you can try from Editor option of XCODE, select tabbar controller you have added from storyboad then go to Editor->Embedded in, you will see that navigation bar controller is disable.
This is also give you idea that it will not work.

Comment: That was the previous way. The problem is that quite a few tabs give rise to navigations, and that forces me to pepper the storyboard with navigation controllers to show modally. I hoped to have a cleaner solution this way, but apparently I went farther then Apple...