# How to maintain UITabBar with segue

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbar

So, I have an hierarchy which is(see image for better understanding): Navigation Controller -> Tab Bar Controller -> VC1,2,3,4,5

All good, all working.

Now, if I segue from one those VCs I lose my Tab Bar. Which I believe it is weird, since they all have a connection to the Tab Bar Controller VC.

Any way I can maintain it?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TabBarController in NavigationController does not show TabBar in viewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682640/tabbarcontroller-in-navigationcontroller-does-not-show-tabbar-in-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 1):

you should not add UITabBarController inside UINavigationController, but you should add each UIViewController managed by UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController

like the following image [image]

Comment: Hi @omartarek, for some reason my Navigation bar doesn't show up on the other two bars... is that normal?

Comment: can you please clarify  with screenshots ? @tateNate78g3